# Unknown js file with fancybox

Tags: php, html, fancybox

I have a main page with a form. This form is sent with ajax as you can see there.

Main page

```
<form action="" method="post" class="newsletter">
    <input type="email" id="nl-email" name="nl-email" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo _('Entrez votre adresse mail'); ?>" required>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="nl_submit" name="nl_submit" class="newsletter_submit"><?php echo _('OK'); ?></a>
</form>
```

Here is the js file where i send the form

```
$('.newsletter_submit').click(function(e) {
    newsletter_submit();
});

function newsletter_submit() {
email = $('#nl-email').val();
rgpd = $('#nl-rgpd').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlsite + 'newsletter.php',
        data: {
            'email': email,
            'rgpd': rgpd
        },
        beforeSend : function() {
        },
        success: function(xml){
            resultat    = $('result', xml).text();
            msg       = $("msg", xml).text();

            if(resultat=='OKrgpd'){
                // form
                var group   = [ {href : msg, title : false} ];
                var options = {
                    width       : '100%',
                    fitToView   : false,
                    autoSize    : true,
                    padding:0,
                    openEffect : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',
                    type : 'iframe',
                    closeBtn : false,
                    helpers : {
                        overlay : {
                            closeClick: false
                        }
                    }
                }
                $.fancybox.open( group, options );
            }
            else {
                // print error 
                alert(msg);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The issue is with the fancybox

```
function t_accueil_popupRgpd($mail) {
?>
<form action="" method="post" class="newsletter">
    <div class="container">
    <input type="hidden" name="nl-email" id="nl-email" value="<?php echo $mail ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="nl-rgpd" id="nl-rgpd" value="ok">
        <h3>RGPD </h3>
        <p>texte rgpd</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-right text-center-xs">
                <a href="<?php echo getUrl("/"); ?>" target="_top" class="btn btn-default btn-block-xs fancy-close"><?php echo _('No'); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-left text-center-xs">
                <a href="<?php echo getUrl("/"); ?>" onclick="newsletter_submit()" target="_top" class="btn btn-success btn-block-xs"><?php echo _('Yes'); ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
</form>
<?php
}
```

When I try to send the form after validation I got an error telling me there the onclick function "newsletter_submit" is unkown but I can't really understand why because the fancybox is called above the first main page and in that page the function is well known. I might be missing something but I can't see what's wrong.

Thanks for your help

Comment: In contrary to the title, your issue is not related to fancybox. Most likely your `newsletter_submit()` function does not exist in the output. It is not possible to give proper answer without seeing live page.

Comment: @Janis Considering I didn't know where the error came...so excuse me for being dump and not having your knowledge, but if you know from where it comes I will be greatfull. Thanks

Comment: I already explained that it is not possible to help you just by looking at these pieces of code. If you see something like `referenceError: newsletter_submit is not defined`, then ... your function is not defined ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what your `HTML` structure is because you haven't included your html header. But I take it you are including both scripts.

Something a long the lines of script `src="fancybox.js"`

If so, you are probably getting the error because of the order that you are including the scripts. It needs to be

```
script src="js file"
script src="fancybox.js"
```

If it is, the other way round, you'd get the error because like it rightly says, `JS script` is unknown.

If this is not the case can you share more of your script (mainly your html header)

Comment: I still have the issue I add the script

Comment: in fact can't find it in the header...it's settle with an internal framework and I can't see the js file in the source code...even on the page where it works